# Should a "no op" function be implemented in Lua or in C?

Tags: lua, gettext, no-op

I have the following function that simply returns its string argument:

```
function N_(s)
  return s
end
```

You may recognize this function name from [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext). It's a marking for the benefit of the .pot extractor only.

Would it be more efficient to implement N_() in C or in Lua?

Can you give me a rule of thumb?

Another question:

Let's say I have a function a bit more complicated:

```
function Z_(s)
  return dict[s] or s
end
```

Would it be more efficient to implement Z_() in C or in Lua?

(I'll be calling both N_() and Z_() from Lua code, not from C code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions implemented in Lua that aren't very processor-intensive are very likely to be more efficient than those in C, if you're spending most of your time in Lua. This is especially true if you end up using [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) at some time in the future. The compiler will always be able to infer more information from your function if it's in the language than if it's some obscure C function which it doesn't know anything about, and it doesn't have to do as much hopping around different contexts.

The problem with implementing `Z_` in C is that you would also have to implement `dict` in C, where Lua already has such functionality in place. So, it depends if you need some specially optimized hash map, maybe C would be better.

---

If your concern is about function call efficiency, why not just cache the results?

```
-- instead of doing:
print(Z_('Hello world! My name is %1!', 'Lua'))
-- perhaps do this:
local greeting = Z_('Hello world! My name is %1!', 'Lua')
print(greeting)
-- reuse greeting at some later time.
```

Of course, your `Z_` function doesn't look like it takes substitutions *yet*, but I assume it might later. However, if you never need substitutions, you may as well make it a table like this:

```
local Z = setmetatable({}, {__index = function(t,k) return k end})
Z['greetings'] = 'Hello world!'
print(Z['greetings']) -- Hello world!
print(Z['goodbye']) -- goodbye
```

This table has an `__index` metamethod which returns the key used, if the table does not have such an entry.

Comment: How about using weak table in last example?

Answer (score 5):

I haven’t measured the difference in this case but I expect writing it in Lua will be faster. Calling C functions is somewhat more expensive.

As a rule of thumb, write it all in Lua, unless it's a long task for which there exists a library C function.

Keep in mind that you'll probably be much more productive writing Lua code than C code. You're thus likely to get it right sooner in Lua. The performance will probably be good enough.

In all cases, YMMV and so measure it yourself.

Comment: Very good point about being more productive writing Lua code than C code. Efficiency is not just computer efficiency but also human efficiency.